# When clicking on submit from my searchform it takes me to home.php

Tags: search, google-search

I'm trying to setup the search feature for my website but when I try to search something it keeps taking me to my home page.

I have created searchpage.php and I've added it to my theme, I've taken the URL and added that to a searchform.php.

Here's the code for my searchform:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

I'm thinking it might be something to do with my template structure? If you need more information just ask. Thanks.

Comment: You are redirecting to a server level 404 page. Something is happening before WordPress even gets involved, at least when I try it.

Comment: The site isn't live, I'm still developing locally.

Comment: though I should add I have setup my lamp stack to use the name lart.co.uk. Not sure if that would make a difference?

Comment: See my answer, but if you are local you will need to create that `action` link dynamically instead of having it hard-coded.

Comment: instead of home_url should I not change that to the equivalent of searchpage.php?

Comment: ^^ I don't know. I am following your lead of apparently trying to submit to a particular "Page".

Comment: [`searchform.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form) is the form itself, though, not the page that processes it.

Comment: Yea, search _page_ .php  is the page that should process it yes? :)

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes. I am doing too many things at once.

Comment: Hi again :) I'm sure I read in the wordpress codex that I shouldn't name my search page search.php. After a while and since the 2011 blog uses it I decided to name it search.php, and now it works. I am so confused right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Extrapolating from your broken code isn't working. If you can explain in human terms exactly what you want, step by step, this might go better.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, when I tried that code I ended up on a server level 404 page. If this is meant to be a standard WordPress search ( ia m not sure if it is) you need to be using `name="s"` and not `name="q"`. WordPress uses the `s` `GET` variable for a search.

The following submits to whatever page I specify in my install:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo site_url('sample-page')?>">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="q" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

So does this:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo get_permalink(2); ?>">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="q" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

Per comments above, `searchpage.php` is the WordPress search page. If you want that page to process your form, you need to use `name="s"` and not `name="q"`. That is the trigger for WordPress to search. You can then hook to `pre_get_posts` to alter how the query is processed.

Comment: I plan to use google custom search when it's live, I just want to get some kind of search working for now. I've changed 'name="q"' to "s" not but I'm still getting directed to the homepage.

Comment: @KyleJoseph : See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your search form action url with home_url( '/' ) and setting search name to "s" as shown in the following code.

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'lart' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still takes me to my homepage :/

Comment: Is this http://lart.co.uk/ your home page which is diplaying under construction message?

Comment: lart.co.uk is the domain yes, but I'm developing locally at the moment. I've update my form code in the question.